# Oracle SQL - select first result only if column X equals Y

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT location, property_id, MIN(year_week) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE first_day='Mon' AND part_full_flag='F' 
GROUP BY location, property_id, full_week_start
```

This gives me a list of the first available date of holiday properties which have a start day of Monday.

The table has another column - "full_week_start" - which gives the exact start date formatted 'DD-MM-YYYY'

What I want to do now is show only the results where the start date is on the first of the month.

If I add full_week_start into the query, it shows the first row starting on 1st of the month, not the first row only is it is starting on 1st of the month.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: SAMPLE DATA**

```
location | property_id | year_week | first_day | part_full_flag | full_week_start
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A        | 1           | 201434    | Mon       | F              | 18-08-2014
A        | 1           | 201435    | Mon       | F              | 25-08-2014
A        | 1           | 201436    | Mon       | F              | 01-09-2014
A        | 2           | 201434    | Mon       | F              | 18-08-2014
A        | 2           | 201435    | Mon       | F              | 25-08-2014
A        | 2           | 201449    | Mon       | F              | 01-12-2014
```

And I only want to return 2 rows from these - looking like this...

```
location | property_id | MIN(year_week)
---------------------------------------
A        | 1           | 201436
A        | 2           | 201449
```

And here's an SQL Fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9d64/3

Comment: So FULL_WEEK_START is a character column formatted as DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: Yeah... not my data so don't criticise the formatting!! So I need something like `full_week_start LIKE '01-'`

Comment: I think you're looking for `FULL_WEEK_START LIKE '01-%'`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
SELECT location, property_id, MIN(year_week) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE first_day='Mon' 
AND part_full_flag='F' 
AND full_week_start like '01%'
GROUP BY location, property_id, full_week_start
```

Update:

```
SELECT location, property_id, MIN(year_week) 
FROM mytable
WHERE first_day='Mon' 
AND part_full_flag='F' 
AND property_id IN (SELECT distinct property_id FROM mytable where full_week_start like '01%')
GROUP BY location, property_id
```

Comment: This selects the min year week that has a start date beginning '01-' - not the min year week if it begins '01-'

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the difference, any chance you could post some sample data and results?

Comment: Your updated query returns the same year_week for both rows in the results... close though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location, property_id, MIN(year_week) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE first_day='Mon' AND part_full_flag='F'
AND TO_CHAR(full_week_start,'MM/DD/YY') LIKE '01%'
GROUP BY location, property_id
```

Comment: I think you'd want to use 'DD/MM/YY' as the formatting string.  Per OP's note above, however, the data is already in character format so it appears it would be reasonable to use `FULL_WEEK_START LIKE '01%'` without having to try to convert it to character first.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
SELECT location, property_id, MIN(year_week) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE first_day='Mon' AND part_full_flag='F' 
GROUP BY location, property_id, full_week_start
HAVING full_week_start LIKE '01%'
```